# Are contiguity matrix and adjacency matrix the same?

Tags: topology, gis-principle, autocorrelation, adjacency

I'm am sorry for that beginner question.
To start the calculation of a spatial auto-correlation value, the book I'm reading writes that we will starting to construct a contiguity matrix.

[image]

Looking at it, it looks really like the adjacency matrix I've learned about, years ago...

But are they the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

An online comparer has this for "contiguous":

- The state of being adjacent or contiguous; contiguity; as, the adjacency of lands or buildings.

I'd say "adjacent" was the normal spoken English word, and "contiguous" is just a bit technical. "Adjacent" can often mean "very close" and not necessarily "sharing a border". For example, "he was sitting at an adjacent table" means at the next nearest table, not that the tables were contiguous.

But in GIS-talk about matrices and polygons, contiguous = adjacent = contiguous.